# fast metabolism and law of conservation of energy

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, food, nutrition

Usually if person take more calories with food than he spends, he is gaining weight.

But if he has fast metabolism, his weight stays the same.

Where these calories go? Maybe food is not completely digesting?

**PS**. How it related to [Basal metabolic rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate)?

Comment: "fast metabolism" usually refers to the daily energy expenditure, also known as the *metabolic rate* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate)  Incomplete uptake of nutrients ("not completely digesting") is distinct from metabolic rate. So it sound like your question is whether metabolic rate *or* nutrient uptake is the key factor?

Comment: @Roland, I just want to understand how this metabolism works, why people can stay slim. So you saying that they waste more energy, so they have low energy conversion efficiency?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that (and I don't know what you mean by "conversion efficiency"). I'm trying to figure out more precisely what you're asking. If a person has a high caloric intake and does not gain weight, then obviously there is either high energy expenditure ("fast metabolism"), or there is incomplete uptake of nutrients, or both. This varies between individuals. Are you asking for population data / studies on metabolic rate, or on digestion, or ... ?

Comment: @Roland, I'm interested in fast metabolism mechanics, how it's actually works in simple terms. About Energy conversion efficiency: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_conversion_efficiency

Comment: probably relation with Basal metabolic rate

Comment: One known mechanism is how efficient your mitochondria are, or more precisely how leaking your mitochondria membranes are. https://dl.sciencesocieties.org/publications/jas/abstracts/87/14_suppl/0870064

Comment: @John, tried to read, but difficult to understand

Comment: It is alright, most of mechanisms are still poorly understood but one that is is the the membrane that the ATP pump sits in, it varies in how effective a barrier to protons it is. brown fats cells have mitochondria that leak like a sieve so they they just pump protons endlessly and make very little ATP but in the process make a lot of heat. That's an extreme case but there is some variation in normal mitochondria as well making the more or less efficient at producing a proton gradient to run ATP pumps. How much of an impact this has is still under investigation.

Comment: @John, so it's losing some energy by heat? maybe you can write something like this as an answer?